# How to extract information from incoming emails to automate checklist?

Tags: java, email, powershell, outlook

In the company I work for, we use a backup software that sends an email to us when a backup completes or fails. Every morning, I go through those emails, verify that every system has reported and that all the reports indicate a successful backup. If a system reports a failed backup, I have to make note of it, and if a system fails to report, I have to make a note of that as well. I am looking to automate this task because it takes too much time during the day that could be spent on more important projects, but the backup checklist MUST be checked every day due to the importance of the information being backed up.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this, preferably in Java or PowerShell, that could look at incoming messages sent to the backup notification address, look at the subject line for an account name and the indication of successful or failed backup, and then look in the message body for the computer name and backup name, then report the list of backups expected versus the list of backups received.

To be clear, I don't need the whole program to be written for me, I just need to know where I should start. If this is possible in a programming language, what should I use?

Email comes in from Office365 to a dedicated email address, so there wouldn't be any additional messages that would need to be ignored or filtered out. Outlook is obviously capable of checking the message body and subject, so if writing an add-on for that is the best way to go, I am totally okay with that.

Comment: So, your mailbox is on Office365? If so, you should be able to access it with IMAP.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also POP3 and Exchange.

Comment: Well, then, where is the problem? You can use JavaMail or something similar to read the messages and parse them, and then you can do anything you wish with the subject, the body contents etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes, There is a way to do this.

**Long Answer:**
You can achieve this in both Java and Powershell, Choose the language that works best for you and you know well.

Powershell can use the outlook com object and connect to the running outlook instance or connect to the mail server and read through the mailbox there. That is how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you. Brilliant. I actually don't know either Java or PowerShell, but I ordered the books for both already so I could learn them. This means that I will be starting with PowerShell since that sounds like the easier option.